# Change content view of Laravel layout without page refresh

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I've been searching for an hour on how to nagivate within my Laravel website without refreshing the website (page layout), but I couldn't find a proper solution: one that not just loads the HTML, but actually replaces the content view within the layout.

This is my current dashboard:

So when clicking on a menu item within the blue area, I want the red content area to change without page refresh. What would be a scalable solution for this? I'm trying to follow the DRY (Don't repeat yourself) principle as much as possible.

Oh, please don't mark this topic as a clone of other topics as I've seen most of them but without proper solution. Hope anyone can help me out.

Comment: You'd probably want to use laravel as an entry point to vue, and not use blade at all (aside from the vue index).

Comment: Also, you might want to google `laravel vue spa`

Comment: What's the difference between laravel as an entry point to vue.js and using vue.js in a regular laravel environment?

Comment: `vue` is rendered on the client side and doesn't refresh the site, `laravel` always requires a page reload

Comment: So essentially what you're asking for is impossible with just laravel, you need a third party library, like Vue, to handle this

Comment: I get this error when running npm run dev: 'Error: Can't resolve '@/components/dashboard.vue' in '..\resources\assets\js''', how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can get this done by using jQuery [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function -

```
$(function () {
    $("#menu_option_a").on("click", function () {
        $("#dashboard").load("View1.html");
    });
    $("#menu_option_b").on("click", function () {
        $("#dashboard").load("View2.html");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This only loads the html as far as I know.

Comment: Woah there, Hello 2008

Comment: @Derek hah, just curious. what does `hello 2008` means?

Comment: @Sphinx before NPM came out, this was a popular design pattern for some to mimic a single page application without having to refresh

Answer (score 0):

Changing a view without page load means we need to use the ajax techology. Vuejs is a frontend frameework the allows us to acomplish that easily with its axios library